# Missing InnoDB In WHM MySQL 5.5 Upgrade?

Tags: mysql, whm

I am running WHM 11.32.2 and upgraded MySQL to 5.5 via the official production ready upgrade from WHM.

However, for some reason, I cannot create any InnoDB tables? They keep being created as MyISAM. Also, under phpMyAdmin, InnoDB does not even show up as a option from the drop down menu.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. open etc/my.cnf
2. search fot "skip-innodb." comment it out.
3. restart mysql service.